# How to read a line of string from a particular location

Tags: c#, .net, string, io, stream

I'm working with a really really big file. I'm talking about gigabyte big.

I need to be able to read a line from a particular index as the textfile is consistently being updated. What is the fastest possible solution for achieving this? I am not constrained by space requirement at all.

Edit: More detailed info posted. Suppose I have the following text that needs to be read:

```
Jun 21 09:47:53 ez-x5 user.debug if_comm: [TX] 30 40 05 
Jun 21 09:47:53 ez-x5 user.debug if_comm: [RX] 04 
Jun 21 09:47:53 ez-x5 user.debug if_comm: [TX] 30 40 05 
Jun 21 09:47:54 ez-x5 user.debug if_comm: [RX] 02 30 40 0f 30 32 31 23 64 31 30 32 30 64 64 49 49 49 49 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 64 03 0b
```

This textfile is consistently updated by our logger. When the text file gets updated, I need to read the new line (separated by \n) of whatever is appended to the log.

Comment: What is "a line"? Any line? The next in a sequence? By line number? Also, what is your "particular index"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a FileStream object you can get random access in the file by changing the Position property.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0bs3w9t).

When setting the Position it seeks to the position in the stream, so you will need to know ahead of time about where in the file you want to start looking from.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lineCounter` variale and increment it when you read `StreamReader.ReadLine()`. When you reach a specific index (ie. `lineCounter==SpecificIndex`) then stop reading.

Comment: How? I need to read the new line when the text file gets updated. As far as I'm concerned, you would have to start reading from index 0 again once you want to start reading the file again.

Comment: I'd suggest `File.ReadAllLines` if your text file is *small* but in this case (huge text file) you've (I think) to use *counter*.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) you can map a part of a file into your memory (so you don't read in the full file). By combining this with a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) you should be able to get a quite good solution to work.